# How to treat Disabled JS on Browser

Tags: javascript, meta, noscript

I have tried this code..
but on my first refresh of the browser it echoes the meta tag... then when I refresh it again it redirects to my warning page.. Is it the actual behavior of the `noscript` tag? I thought It'll just redirect me to my warning page the first time I refresh the browser... but it first echoes the `Meta tag`

```
<noscript>
  <META id="refresh"  HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=<?=base_url()?>MainController/WarningPage/1">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***noscript*** tag is used basically to define a section of HTML to be displayed if the JS is disabled in the browser or the script type on that page is unsupported.

To redirect immediately you can try this:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=yourURL.html">
</noscript>
```

However, the browser might inform the user that he will be redirected forcing its interaction.

Comment: still the same.. my first refresh of the browser echoes the meta tag instead of redirecting...

Comment: Weird, just tried it and it works for me. Can you share more info? Is it an HTML?

Comment: my bad I put the noscript inside the body tag...